# Mapping a number to bit position in C

Tags: c, serial-communication, bit-fields

I'm developing an programm running on Atmel AT90CAN128. Connected to this controller there are 40 devices, each with a status (on/off). As I need to report the status of each of this devices to a PC through Serial Communication, I have 40 bits, which define whether the device is on or off. In addition, the PC can turn any of this devices on or off.

So, my first attempt was to create the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
     unsigned char length;      //!< Data Length
     unsigned data_type;        //!< Data type
     unsigned char data[5];     //!< CAN data array 5 * 8 = 40 bits
} SERIAL_packet;
```

The problem with this was that the PC will send an `unsigned char address` telling me the device to turn on/off, so accessing the bit corresponding to that `address` number turned out to be rather complicated...

So I started looking for options, and I stumbled upon the C99 `_Bool` type. I thought, great so now I'll just create a `_Bool data[40]` and I can access the `address` bit just by indexing my `data` array. Turns out that in C (or C++) memory mapping needs an entire byte for addressing it. So even if I declare a `_Bool` the size of that `_Bool` will be 8 bits which is a problem (it needs to be as fast as possible so the more bits I send the slower it gets, and the PC will be specting 40 bits *only*) and not very efficient for the communication. So I started looking into Bit Fields, and tried the following:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char length;   //!< Data Length
    unsigned data_type;     //!< Data type
    arrayData data[40]; //!< Data array 5 bytes == 40 bits
} SERIAL_packet;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char aux : 1;
} arrayData;
```

And I wonder, is this going to map that `data[40]` into a consequent memory block with a size of 40 bits (5 bytes)?

If not, is there any obvious solution I'm missing? This doesn't seem like a very complicated thing to do (would be much simpler if there were less than 32 devices so I could use a `int` and just access through a bit mask).

Comment: just use **boolean data[40]**

Comment: What are the range of values you get for the addresses?  Is it 0 - 39 or something else?

Comment: Thetr is no way to address a bit. (BTW, a `char` is a byte not an octet if your code need an octet use `uint8_t`, this is more pedantic and disallow the compilation of your code on machine where this would not work as expected)

Comment: "And I wonder, is this going to map that data[40] into a consequent memory block with a size of 40 bits (5 bytes)?" => short answer => No. Why don't you look yourself with `SERIAL_packet foo; printf("%zu, zu\n", sizeof foo, sizeof foo.data);` ?

Comment: "The problem with this was that the PC will send an unsigned char address telling me the device to turn on/off, so accessing the bit corresponding to that address number turned out to be rather complicated..." you are clearly into a XY problem, please describe with more precision this part of your question.

Comment: Is std::bitset available? Have you considered xor? If you want a command to change one specific address, you don't need all 40 bits, just that one address.

Comment: @Stargateur, yes, will change it to `uint8_t`, thanks. Yes the PC will send 0 - 39. "you are clearly into a XY problem" I'm not sure what you meant there. But the issue was accessing bit number `address`, but seems @dbush figured it out. I've been reading about low level bit masking but it's definitely not my forte.
Thanks everyone

Comment: @TomasAmbrogi Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the addresses you get back are in the range 0 - 39 and that a `char` has 8 bits, you can treat your `data` array as an array of bits:

```
| data[0]                       | data[1]                           ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

To set bit `i`:

```
packet.data[i/8] |= (1 << (i%8));
```

To clear bit `i`:

```
packet.data[i/8] &= (1 << (i%8)) ^ 0xff;
```

To read bit `i`:

```
 int flag = (packet.data[i/8] & (1 << (i%8)) != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.